# How resize automatically textures?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm working with Libgdx and the textures are placed correctly when resizing, but not resized. How can I solve this?

My code:

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.setViewport(width, height, true);
        stage.getCamera().translate(-stage.getGutterWidth(),
                -stage.getGutterHeight(), 0);

        start.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/10f * 2f, stage.getHeight()/10f * 5f);
        soundOff.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/10f * 3.5f, stage.getHeight()/10f * 2f);
        soundOn.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/10f * 3.5f, stage.getHeight()/10f * 2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only changing their position "*.setPosition", set its new size too.